# Report / Dashboard for Tasks I'm following

Tags: reporting, chatter, tasks, dashboard, follow

I want to produce a report/dashboard to show Tasks a User is following.

Context:

---

A task is created by a User and assigned to a group leader. The group leader will then reassign the task to a subordinate.

Ie For Task X: A assigns to B. B reassigns to C.

A needs to know when the (reassigned) Task is In Progress, or Complete, etc.

---

It appears that a Task owner field changes when the Task is reassigned; Task X will have CreatedBy as B and Owner C. There is nothing in the Task object to indicate A's original ownership.

A solution is for User A to become a follower of the Task.

Activity on the Task is then shown in A's feed panel. However, this is transient information.

User A needs to know when the (reassigned) Task is complete, so needs a report to show the status of all the Tasks she's following.

I can't see a way to do this. In fact I can't see any way to report on any Chatter type objects.

I found this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YfNMAA0

Is it still the case that Chatter is "unreportable"?

Can I add some kind of related list type object to the user's home page that would show them the status of followed Tasks? (Ie is there a non-report based solution)

Comment: At the moment, [this is an idea in the Salesforce Success community](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IAo6AAG). Up-vote it and hopefully it will be released sometime.